# SQL Query: find customers who purchased more than one book in a given year

Tags: sql

This is the DB Schema:

```
Books (bookid, title, author, year)
Customers (customerid, name, email)
Purchases (customerid, bookid, year)
Reviews (customerid, bookid, rating)
Pricing (bookid, format, price)
```

How do I find customers (show their names and email addresses) who purchased more than one book in year 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty much exactly like your english language question phrased it... just translated into SQL ...

```
Select * From Customers C
Where (Select Count(*) From Purchases
       Where customerid = C.customerid
           And Year = 2003) > 1
```

Comment: And yours woorks as well.  +1 to you.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(p.customerId) as purchases_in_2003
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Purchases p ON c.customerId = p.customerId
WHERE p.year = 2003
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING purchases_in_2003 > 1
```

Comment: you forgot the GROUP BY clause, but otherwise this is the best answer so far

Comment: Deleted my own answer because I read the question wrong, and you answred correctly.  +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative:

```
select
  cu.name
 ,cu.email
 ,count(*) as books_purchased
from
  customers cu
 ,purchases pu
where cu.customerid = pu.customerid
  and pu.year = 2003
group by
  cu.name
 ,cu.email
having
  count(*) > 1
```